# What might be the intention of printing a stream to itself?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to build a third-party C++ code base in which there are several places where an attempt is made to print an output stream to itself.  This example demonstrates an expression of the same form:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    std::cout << std::cout << "Say what?" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I find that without any options, g++ 4.8.5 accepts that code with zero complaints, but g++ 8.2.1 rejects it with a good old "no match for ‘operator<<’" error.

**I understand the error**.  What I want to know is whether there is any reason to think that it was ever anything other than an error -- was there a C++ version or a widely used C++ compiler that would do something useful with such code?  Although it accepts the code, g++ 4.8.5 is not such a compiler in my book because the program it builds evaluates the first `<<` operation simply by outputting a hexadecimal number of unclear significance.

I have considered that it might be a simple typo, maybe magnified by copy & paste.  For example, perhaps the second `std::cout` was an accidental duplicate of the first, or perhaps it was meant to be `std::endl`, instead.  However, in a different source file in the same code base I see the same idiom of an output stream being printed to itself applied to objects of type `std::stringstream`, which suggests to me that it might be intentional.

My overall objective is to decide how best to fix the code.

Comment: Unless the original author can tell you otherwise I'd just go with the typo explanation

Comment: ...and there is not custom overload for `ostream& operator<<(ostream&,ostream&)` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, there is a lot of code to search through, but since g++ 8.2.1 rejects the original code, I am inclined to think that there is no custom overload.

Comment: It's possible it was some sort of tracking mechanism and the code was inserting the address of the object into the stream so you know which stream was responsible. `ostream` used to decay to a `void*` and it has an overload for printing `void*`'s

Comment: this seems to have been fixed in gcc 6 https://godbolt.org/z/x6xDRw

Comment: g++ 8.2.1 vs g++4.8.5 is both with the same C++ standard? C++11?

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's a C++ standard change.  C++98/03 it was okay.  C++11 removed the conversion operator that made it work.

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's not a bug. It's just that at some point, GCC switched to having C++11 be the default version of the standard.

Comment: Thanks, @NathanOliver, that's the explanation I was looking for.  Although it doesn't tell me for sure what the author's intent was, it shows me a way toward eliciting the same behavior from modern implementations that the code produced in older ones, which is a satisfactory outcome.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sounds good.  The only reason I don't think it is a typo is because it does actually change what it "printined" and I would think that would be noticed.  Would you like me to move it to an answer?  It didn't because it was just a best guess.

Comment: @NathanOliver, if you make an answer of that then I will at least UV it.  I'm torn between which answer I should accept in that case, given that eerorika has already posted much the same explanation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'll just let his stand.  He covers why this used to work, and the rest is just speculation on both our parts.

Comment: What's preventing you from _asking the third party_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What might be the intention of printing a stream to itself?

It is probably unintentional, or the intention itself was a mistake.

The difference between the GCC versions is the default dialect of C++ that they use. The newer GCC defaults to c++11 or newer. The program should compile with the newer compiler as long as you use a pre-C++11 dialect.

The change in C++11 was the removal of implicit conversion from `std::basic_ios` to `void*`. The purpose of this conversion was to check for failure state of the stream: null signified a failed stream while non-null signified a valid stream which allows the pattern `if(stream >> input)`. In C++11 the conversion was replaced with *explicit* conversion to `bool`. Since the new conversion is explicit, it won't be applied to inserting a stream into stream. This was a backwards incompatible change which was presumably considered to not be a problem since the now-incompatible ways of using the conversion (such as the example) would have had no practical uses. In fact, it is useful to get a compilation error when doing something that has no practical use.

> My overall objective is to decide how best to fix the code.

Probably just remove the insertion of `cout` into `cout`. If you're concerned that the output must remain same because it might be parsed by another program, then you can output any non-zero hex number to keep the output same for the sake of compatibility.